# Печень или печенка

Tags: стилистика

Как все-таки правильно писать в кулинарных изданиях: печень или печенка? Или допустимы оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Если верить словарям, то правилен второй вариант.
ПЕЧЕНЬ, -и; ж.
Крупная железа человека и животных, участвующая в процессах пищеварения, обмена веществ и кровообращения и обеспечивающая постоянство внутренней среды организма. Болезни печени. У него п. не в порядке. ***Тресковая п.*** Цирроз п.
(хроническое прогрессирующее заболевание печени). < Печёночный (см.).
ПЕЧЁНКА, -и; мн. род. -нок, дат. -нкам; ж.
1.
***Печень животного. Жареная п. Пирог с печёнкой. Любить печёнку. Паштет из печёнки. Куриная п.
2. Разг.***
**=Печень. П. заболела. Греть печёнку.**
3. обычно мн.: печёнки, -нок. Разг.
Внутренности вообще, нутро. От тряски печёнки болят. Печёнкой чуять что-л. Отбить, отшибить (все) печёнки. Продрог, промок до (самых) печёнок, до (самой) печёнки
(очень сильно, до самого нутра). ◊ Всеми печёнками (хотеть, ненавидеть и т.п.). Разг.
Очень сильно. Сидеть, засесть в печёнках у кого; въелся, влез в печёнки кому. Разг.
О том, кто (что) сильно беспокоит, досаждает, надоедает. < Печёночный (см.).
(Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).
ПЕЧЁНКА
    ПЕЧЁНКА, печёнки, жен.
    ***1. только ед. Печень животного, как пища. Телячья печёнка.***
    (Толковый словарь Ушакова).
    ПЕЧЕНКА 1. ж. разговорное 1) То же, что печень. 2) а) ***Печень животного как продукт питания.*** б) ***Кушанье, приготовленное из такого продукта.*** 3) Употр. как символ источника гнева, раздражения, желчного настроения. 2. ж. местн. ***То, что испечено или запечено.***
    (Толковый словарь Русского Языка).

Answer (score 1):

Если не вдаваться в филологические изыски, то в профессиональном плане будет правильно писать ***печень***. "Печенка" - кушанье (см. Серж), в качестве ингредиента, да и во всех остальных случаях, - печень.

Так что в меню, рецептуре и проч -  печень. Но как разговорная форма "печенка" вполне приемлемо и в более широком значении.